# How to sort a dataframe by a timestamp column formatted as "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" for Shiny R script

Tags: r, sorting, datetime, shiny

I want to display a table of values ordered by date and time values where the user could sort the table clicking on headers.

It's supposed to run on a Shiny/R script, through a renderDataTable, but is the same behavior we get in RStudio browsing data frames.

[image: data frame]

d1 is in the original format, it sorts like strings, so I tried having d2 as   POSIXct version, it works, but I doesn't solve my problem of displaying just d1.

```
myTS <- data.frame(d1=c("01/01/2016 10:00:45", 
                           "01/02/2016 10:00:45",
                           "01/03/2016 10:00:45",
                           "01/04/2016 10:00:45",
                           "10/01/2016 15:00:45",
                           "15/01/2016 15:00:45")) 
                            myTS$d2 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(myTS$d1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

How to display just d1 formatted as "%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S" but get it correctly ordered as it works when converted to POSIXct?

Thanks

Joao

Comment: Just use something like `myTS <-data.frame(d1[order(d2)])`. Your just reordering d1 based on d2.

Comment: but this way I get the data frame ordered just for the fist time, as the user clicks on the header of table it will sort based on the strings of that column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not the easiest way, but if you really want this functionality, then here you go:

Modifying the way in which DT sorts its entries will not be possible. But we can change the way it formats the output. So why not store the datetime as numeric value (where sorting will be no problem) and just display it as date value.

There is a standard formatter (`formatDate()`) that does easy (but ugly) datetime conversion. But if you want something specific, you will have to format this with JavaScript (which is not that hard if you already have a template to work on).

Under [this link](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html), Chapter 4.5 you will find some general information about having a formatting function using `rowCallback`. I used this plus some lengthy manual DateTime formatting with JavaScript.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
))

server <- function(input, output){
  myTS <- data.frame(d1=c("01/01/2016 10:00:45", 
                           "01/02/2016 10:00:45",
                           "01/03/2016 10:00:45",
                           "01/04/2016 10:00:45",
                           "10/01/2016 15:00:45",
                           "15/01/2016 15:00:45",
                           "16/04/2016 01:00:00")) 
  myTS$d2 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(myTS$d1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
  myTS$d3 <- as.integer(myTS$d2)

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(myTS, options = list(rowCallback = JS("
      function(row, data){
      /* Create a Date. Note: R stores time in seconds, JavaScript in milliseconds. data[3] marks the third column. + converts to numeric. */ 
      var date = new Date(+data[3]*1000);
      /* I found this pad function somewhere on StackOverflow. */
      function pad(n) {return n < 10 ? '0'+n : n;}
      /* If you'd like some other format, change it here. */
      var dateString = pad(date.getDate()) + '/' + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + pad(date.getHours()) + ':' + pad(date.getMinutes()) + ':' + pad(date.getSeconds());
      $('td:eq(3)', row).html(dateString);
    }")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please notify me if you have questions.
Have fun!

Comment: Great, just what I need, thank you very much. I started to dig into DT as a possible solution, but I just  saw ways through plugins like "datetime" and it seems they are not incorporated into shiny yet.

Comment: @jcarlos Yeah, there are so many thing which should be more easy and more incorporated into shiny. Atm there are so many workarounds necessary.